# External properties file for an executable jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, executable-jar

I'm trying to add an external properties file to an executable jar, but not in succeed for now.

**Question**: Is it impossible to include an external properties file into an executable jar?

When I run my program locally, with putting `batch.properties` under `src/main/resources`, it works fine. But it fails after deploying the jar and `batch.properties`, linking it under `/etc/init.d/`, putting the jar and `batch.properties`

```
/usr/local/myapp/myapp.jar
/usr/local/myapp/batch.properties
/etc/init.d/my-app    --(symlink)-->   /usr/local/myapp/myapp.jar
```

`my-app` can be executable just like an usual service:

```
/etc/init.d/my-app start
```

But it says that some beans cannot be instantiated due to missing placeholders.

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [batch.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.batch.class_name' in string value "${spring.datasource.batch.class_name}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.batch.class_name' in string value "${spring.datasource.batch.class_name}"
```

My pom.xml is like this:

```
<project ...>
  // Some other definitions...

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>my.project.Bootstrap</mainClass>
          <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And the Spring setting is just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ...">
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:batch.properties" />
  <!-- Some bean definitions -->
</beans>
```

Any help or comments would be appreciated so much.

**EDIT**

I couldn't succeed it for now, but alternately I decided to split profiles and include a properties file accordingly into the executable jar.

However it's better to be able to read an external properties file, any help would still be welcomed.

Comment: If all else fails you can explicitly ask the JVM where the jar file containing your classes are, and then go to that directory, locate the property file and load it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an external properties file next to the .jar provided that you call it `application.properties`.

If you cannot rename the properties file, you can also give the path of the external properties file as an option :

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/batch.properties

#Or for executable jars
./myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/batch.properties
```

You can also create a symlink `application.properties` -> `batch.properties`.

See [Externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

**EDIT**

This is my maven config :

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

After mvn clean install, I get 2 jars :

```
backend/target [ ll
total 53M
-rwxr--r-- 1 adenoyelle adenoyelle  53M avril 22 10:56 backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 adenoyelle adenoyelle 353K avril 22 10:56 backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
```

Then, I copy the first jar to the destination folder and place a `configuration.properties` next to it :

```
backend@[...]:~/backend$ ll
total 53900
drwxrwxr-x 2 backend backend     4096 Apr 21 13:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 backend backend     4096 Apr 21 13:56 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 backend backend      511 Apr 20 16:13 application.properties
-rwxr--r-- 1 backend backend 55175294 Apr 20 19:06 backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 backend backend       24 Apr 20 19:20 backend -> backend-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar*
-rw-r--r-- 1 backend backend      179 Apr 20 19:26 backend.service
```

You can see that I also created a file called `backend.service` in order to install the jar as a service via `systemd`.

Here is the content of the file :

```
[Unit]
Description=backend
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=backend
ExecStart=/home/backend/backend
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And there is a symlink to this file in `/etc/systemd/system` :

```
backend@[...]:/etc/systemd/system$ ll | grep backend
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   37 Apr 20 19:23 backend.service -> /home/backend/backend.service
```

Comment: Well, executable jar doesn't have to be executed by java command, so I don't know the way to add the path explicitly.

Comment: @tsuda7 I use an executable jar in my project and placing an `application.properties` next to the jar does the job. Can you try?

Comment: Okay, I missed your second ./jar suggestion. It seems to be the solution, I'll try it! If it works I'll tell you that, please give me some time

Comment: Hi @Arnaud, I'm trying your suggestions, but nothing has changed... I understand how to provide config with my jar in principle, but it doesn't work somehow... Are you using the springboot's executable option, as I do above in pom.xml? What I tried is: rename batch.properties to application properties, add `spring.config.location` option, executing from java command and their combinations.

Comment: @tsuda7 I updated the answer in order to show the config.

Comment: Thank you @Arnaud, it seems that the only difference is if the pom.xml has `<resources>` in it, but now I understand referencing an external properties can work! I'll try it again soon. Thanks again!